# Get process id from DTE (EnvDte)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

Is it possible to get the process id of a visual studio instance through the DTE mDte variable? Refer to code below.

```
    private static DTE mDte;

    public static void OpenVisualStudio()
    {
        Type visualStudioType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
        mDte = Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType) as DTE;

        if (mDte != null)
        {
            mDte.MainWindow.Visible = true;
        }

        // get process id of visual studio instance through mDte
    }
```

Comment: I don't know offhand, but if you inspect the object at runtime you might be able to figure it out.

Comment: I have solved it by:

Comment: You have solved it by doing what? Do share the answer.

Comment: I added a comment above and wanted to give the answer but I could not share code in a comment so I gave the solution in the answer 3 minutes later, refer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done as follows :

```
    public static int OpenVisualStudio()
    {
        var devenv = Process.Start("devenv.exe");

        if (devenv == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        do
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            mDte = GetDte(devenv.Id);
        }
        while (mDte == null);

        return devenv.Id;
    }
```

I got it from here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2011/08/10/how-to-get-dte-from-visual-studio-process-id.aspx

It solves my problem for now...

Answer (score -1):

The `DTE` object has a `Debugger` property which has a `CurrentProcess` property which has a `ProcessID` property.

```
int processId = dte.Debugger.CurrentProcess.ProcessID;
```

Comment: dte.Debugger.CurrentProcess is not the process of the debugger (i.e. a devenv), it's the process that is currently being debugged.